# List splitting in python3

Tags: python

I have a list

```
list = ['i-052b7c00040cad9e8', 1.53, 86.7265358899962, '/', 25.1078055963193, '/run', 10.6200969763866, 'i-0f40cbf93afdb6949', 1.97, 86.6133940961272, '/', 24.2470470317567, '/dev', 0.0]
```

I want to split list in every i-xxxxx and store all separated list in a single list.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Python 3 code (it should work)

```
newList = []
tempA = []

for item in list:

    if "i-" in str(item) and len(tempA) == 0:
        tempA.append(item)
    elif "i-" in str(item) and len(tempA) != 0:
        newList.append(tempA)
        tempA = [item]
    else:
        tempA.append(item)
```

newList contains the list of lists.

PS: Next time, post whatever code you have tried and then seek help. Right now, it seems like you haven't tried and just want the code.

Comment: If my code works, make sure to tick the flag next to my post to 'accept' it (so that others know which solution works)

Comment: I got error   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
>>>

Comment: @RehanCh Sorry, I was thinking in the wrong language ; ( ! I have edited my answer.